# Gimp Problems With Toolbox

Tags: gimp

I'm using gimp 2.8 and weird things are happening to the toolbox. I don't have the size options. I also don't have the option with the Layers - Brushes that is not brushes and gradients. Do you know how to get it back? Thanks!

This is a screenshot of how GIMP looks to me:

[image: Whats happening]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the [tool options dialog](https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-tools.html#gimp-tool-options-dialog), and [drag it back](https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-concepts-docks.html) to the area below the toolbox.

If you want additional tabs in a dock, you can add them via the [tab menu](https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-concepts-docks.html#gimp-dockable-menu) as well.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to  Select file>new or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and then fill out the settings and then you can start using GIMP (GNU Image Manipulation Program).